# Is giving myself write permission on my Python `site-packages` directory a way to avoid `sudo pip` risks?

Tags: macos, security, permissions, python, pip

I understand that there are [security risks involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056000/656912) in installing `pip` under `sudo`, but for various reasons I would like to continue installing my packages in `site-packages` (on OSX 10.9), which currently requires `sudo` for `pip` to work.

Would simply giving myself permission to write to `site-packages` avoid these issues? Are there new security risks associated with doing so? Or perhaps the alternative is to create a new user who owns `site-packages`, specifically for use with `pip`?

---

Note that this is not a question about using virtualenv to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're opening up yourself to a huge security risk. Many system utilities are written in Python that runs under root privilege. If you give yourself write privilege to the system site-packages, you're risking that any program that runs under you (not necessarily python program) can inject malicious code into the system site-packages and obtain root privilege. If you create another user specifically to own the system site-packages, your vector of attack is only malicious setup.py. It's best not to touch the system site packages, and use virtualenv.

Comment: So if I create a user for `pip` and give him access to `site-packages` the only risks I run are (1) that the execution of `setup.py` itself will do something malicious in `site-packages` (and nowhere else) and (2) that something malicious that ends up in `site-packages` will do damage anywhere that any code I run can, correct? Isn't (2) inescapable anyway, for any Python installation?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: it is inescapable, yes, but the impact is different with system site-packages which is regularly run with escalated privileges and virtualenv-ed site-packages which normally runs under your account.

Comment: But does wouldn't virtualenv then pose the same risks as my taking ownership of the systems `site-packages`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: if you run a software with root privilege, you have to make sure that the software and any libraries that it uses cannot be modified by anyone other than root. This includes if you're running a python program that requires root privilege inside a virtualenv.